# Undefined fields in model

Tags: ember-data

I'm learning [ember.js](/questions/tagged/ember.js) (`ember-cli` and `ember-data` = 2.7) and  facing problems using models. Some models appears as 'undefined'

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  revision: DS.attr('number'),
  pub_date: DS.attr('date'),
  contenido: DS.attr('string'),
  contenidoHtml: DS.attr(),
  cambios: DS.attr('string'),
  cambiosHtml: DS.attr(),
  notify: DS.attr('boolean'),
  URI: DS.attr('string'),
  firmas: DS.attr()
});
```

I have a simple serializer, like this:

```
// serializers/application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: 'id'
});
```

This is the response from the API:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "URI": "",
        "cambios": "Commit inicial",
        "cambiosHtml": "<p>Commit inicial</p>",
        "contenido": "No por mucho _madrugar_, amanece más __temprano__.",
        "contenidoHtml": "<p>No por mucho <em>madrugar</em>, amanece más <strong>temprano</strong>.</p>",
        "firmas": {
          ...
          "reviso": "Zamora"
        },
        "notify": false,
        "pub_date": "2011-09-30",
        "revision": 0
      },
      "id": "7a09d345-27cc-45ef-bf58-488354c25239",
      ...
  ],
  "links": {
     ...
  },
  "meta": {
     ...
    }
  }
}
```

Now, according to Ember Inspector, the fields `contenidoHtml`, `cambiosHtml` and `pub_date` are *undefined* or empty.

Do I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

> In Ember Data the convention is to camelize attribute names on a model

`pub_date` - is not follwed this so it should be changed to pubDate

> JSONAPISerializer expects attributes to be dasherized in the document
>   payload returned by your server:

`cambiosHtml` - change it to `cambios-html`
`contenidoHtml`  - change it to `contenido-html`
`pub_date` - change it to `pub-date`

If you dont have control over the API, then you might want to create model specific serializers by running the below ember-cli command,

```
ember generate serializers 'model-name'
```

**app/serializers/model-name.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  attrs: {
    cambiosHtml: 'cambiosHtml',
    contenidoHtml: 'contenidoHtml',
    pubDate: 'pub_date'
  }
});
```

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_attribute-names